# ColdFusion: get url parameter by name

Tags: url, parameters, coldfusion

I want to get in ColdFusion 10 an URL parameter from `CGI.QUERY_STRING` by its name. How to do it without looping?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Any values passed in to a page via the query string are available in the URL scope.

Assume you have a query string that looks like `http://mydomain.com?val1=42&val2=moo` you would access the variables by referencing them as such

```
<cfset myVal1 = url.val1 />
<cfset myVal2 = url.val2 />
```

Or, in cfscript

```
myVal1 = url.val1;
myVal2 = url.val2;
```

To see all the values passed in via query string, you can also dump out the URL scope.

```
<cfdump var="#url#" />
```

or, in cfscript

```
writeDump( url );
```

Comment: Thank you. CF is really new for me. Now the question: how to catch an exception when parameter with given name does not exist?

Comment: you can do `<cfif structKeyExists(url,'val1')>exists<cfelse>doesn't</cfif>`

Comment: Or, you can param the value `<cfparam name="url.val1" default="" />` at top of page. This way, url.val1 will exist, but be an empty string for the rest of the request.