# How to have a short id in a link (Coldfusion)

Tags: redirect, hyperlink, coldfusion, cfml, short-url

I am trying to build our own internal URL shortening service since show many of the main ones are being blocked as spam (we use bit.ly now).

What I would like to do is have a URL with an id attached to it which hits a page, looks up the long URL and then forward it on to it. I'm good with everything but the first part.

Here is the kind of URL I would like to send: http://acbd.us/1234567 or http://acbd.us?1234567 where 1234567 is the id we need to look up. I have seen this with other sites but just have no idea how to go about it without referencing a file (lookup.cfm?id=1234567). The whole point is to make it as short as possible.

I have been searching Stack and elsewhere and can'y find a thing.

Thank you and any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html

Comment: HINT: even when you are not referencing a file in the URL, you ARE referencing a file in the URL. It is the default document. Normally `index.cfm` for ColdFusion. So within that page check for and process the URL query string - [HINT #2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18022252/1636917)

Answer (score 1):

The `http://acbd.us?1234567` is somewhat easier to implement.

1. Web servers such as IIS can be made to automatically associate this with a default document. so it becomes

   http://acbd.us/index.cfm?1234567
2. While we often associate the part after the `?` as defining the `url` variables, it is also a part of `cgi.query_string`

So based on that you could do something like

**index.cfm**

```
<cfscript>
    newloc = QueryExecute("
      SELECT newloc
      FROM lookup
      WHERE shortversion = :shortversion
      ",
      {shortversion = { value : cgi.query_string, CFSQLType : 'CF_SQL_varchar'}},
      { cachedwithin : CreateTimespan(1,0,0,0)}
      ).newloc;

    location(newloc, false);
</cfscript>
```

We want to cache it for a day because

1. It should never change and
2. It needs to be base and
3. It is a very small bit of data

Comment: James you are the KING!!!! that worked perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There are pleanty of free self-hosting options of URL Shorteners if you can't figure out how to make your own.

https://github.com/awesome-selfhosted/awesome-selfhosted#url-shorteners

Comment: Yeah I know and bilty has been great. But we are getting blocked by other provides that prompted us to do this. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. Accepted answer checks are always appreciated. It lets future people know that this was the best solution.

Comment: I will do immediately? How exactly do I do that? Thanks